# Removing string using regular expressions

Tags: c#, html

I would like to replace this string to have the result of `<div>` Can this be done using regular expressions? I know that it will always start with `class=\"` and end with `'\"'` What would be the best way to do this?

```
<div class=\"ExternalClass4A5391EF4ADD4D4896651BC7F467224F\">
```

Comment: Using Regular Expressions to parse html is quite dangerous, slow, and usually not recommended.  Though it is indeed possible, what have you tried though?

Comment: Do not use regex for html parsing. Use `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very straightforward regex for it:

```
"<div class=\"([^\"]*)\">"
```

Parentheses designate the *capturing group*. Once you get a match, get group at index 1 to harvest the result of capturing the content of the match.

Note: I am assuming that this is an exercise, not something that you wish to do in a production environment. There is a number of HTML parsers available for production environments. You should use them, instead of a quick regex-based solution.